# Turning all dates into date ranges

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table in my database called sale:

```
SaleID (PK)
Quantity
Date
Time
TotalPrice
TransactionID (FK)
```

I then have a test table, in the same database with the following structure:

```
SaleID (PK)
DateFrom
DateTo
TotalPrice
AveragePrice
```

In the sale, table I have 60,000 dates. In my test table I would like the `date from` and `date to` be a week. So for example:

```
DateFrom - 1st January 2016.
DateTo - 7th January 2016.
AveragePrice - 20,000
```

It would allow me to view the weekly average sale. Is there any way to take all dates from sale in a 7 day range and insert them into test? I can't think of a query which would make this work. I know how to do a query for one week:

```
SELECT * FROM sale where date between 'January 1 2016' and 'January 7 2016'
```

However I'm unsure how I would insert January 1 2016 as the FromDate and January 7 2016 as the ToDate and do this for every 7 day range. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just use a weekofyear function to return 1-53 based on the date and use it for analysis?  (function varies based on actual RDBMS and you've listed mySQL as well as SQL server so those functions would vary.) ([datePart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) SQL server, [weekofYear](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear) mySQL)

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: @xQbert I wasn't aware of that function. It sounds like an ideal way to go about it though. I'm using MySQL.

Comment: @JoshCaswell  you may need to use [yearWeek](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)  if your analysis will span years.  Note there are 53 weeks sometimes because of where the breaks occur for the function; but it's usually along justifiable lines.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - It does span over a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This one doesnt work. Last week of 2014 say is week 1**

> ```
> SELECT 
>       YEAR(`Date`),
>       WEEKOFYEAR(`Date`),
>       AVG(TotalPrice)
> FROM Sales
> GROUP BY  YEAR(`Date`),
>           WEEKOFYEAR(`Date`)
> ```

`January 1 2016` will have a week with less than 7 days

If you want 7 day weeks, you can use:

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b018e/4)**

```
SELECT 
      SUBDATE(`Date`, WEEKDAY(`Date`)) MondayWeek,
      AVG(`TotalPrice`)
FROM Sales
GROUP BY SUBDATE(`Date`, WEEKDAY(`Date`))
```

I include another query to see how this work

```
SELECT `Date`, WEEKDAY(`Date`), YEAR(`Date`), WEEKOFYEAR(`Date`),  yearWeek(`Date`)
FROM Sales
order by `Date`;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|       Date | WEEKDAY(`Date`) | YEAR(`Date`) | WEEKOFYEAR(`Date`) | YEARWEEK(`Date`) |
|------------|-----------------|--------------|--------------------|------------------|
| 2014-12-24 |               2 |         2014 |                 52 |           201451 |
| 2014-12-25 |               3 |         2014 |                 52 |           201451 |
| 2014-12-26 |               4 |         2014 |                 52 |           201451 |
| 2014-12-27 |               5 |         2014 |                 52 |           201451 |
| 2014-12-28 |               6 |         2014 |                 52 |           201452 |
| 2014-12-29 |               0 |         2014 |  <===>           1 |           201452 | ***
| 2014-12-30 |               1 |         2014 |                  1 |           201452 |
| 2014-12-31 |               2 |         2014 |                  1 |           201452 |
| 2015-01-01 |               3 |         2015 |  <===>           1 |           201452 | ***
| 2015-01-02 |               4 |         2015 |                  1 |           201452 |
| 2015-01-03 |               5 |         2015 |                  1 |           201452 |
| 2015-01-04 |               6 |         2015 |                  1 |           201501 | ***
| 2015-01-05 |               0 |         2015 |                  2 |           201501 |
| 2015-01-06 |               1 |         2015 |                  2 |           201501 |
| 2015-01-07 |               2 |         2015 |                  2 |           201501 |
| 2015-01-08 |               3 |         2015 |                  2 |           201501 |
| 2015-01-09 |               4 |         2015 |                  2 |           201501 |
| 2015-01-10 |               5 |         2015 |                  2 |           201501 |
| 2015-01-11 |               6 |         2015 |                  2 |           201502 |
| 2015-01-12 |               0 |         2015 |                  3 |           201502 |
| 2015-01-13 |               1 |         2015 |                  3 |           201502 |
| 2015-01-14 |               2 |         2015 |                  3 |           201502 |
| 2015-01-15 |               3 |         2015 |                  3 |           201502 |
| 2015-01-16 |               4 |         2015 |                  3 |           201502 |
```

Comment: When I run it, year and weekofyear are null.

Comment: Your Date field is type `DATE` btw dont use those name for variables because are reserved by the lenguaje. Maybe you field need single quotes? check my update

Comment: I just checked the structure, when the data was generated the date column is a string rather than date. So that would be the issue I'm sure.

Comment: Check my second solution. Working sample included.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to see it working. However my dates are varchars in the format "December 26th, 2014". So I think I'll need to convert the dates to datetime format for this to work.

Comment: @Someguywhocodes Wow dont know how convert that into a date, sorry. But maybe that is a different question. Im sure if you copy in Excel he can convert it.

Comment: @Someguywhocodes Try this one `SELECT  STR_TO_DATE('December 26th, 2014', '%M %D, %Y')`  [str_to_date](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/) and [date format](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/)

Comment: I tried that query firstly. I think the problem might be that this only changes the string format but not the column data type, but if I change the data type to datetime then all my dates are automatically changed to 00-00-00

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96085/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-someguywhocodes).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to Rome, so are there to solve this problem.
Best way, in my opinion, introduce a calendar table.

For example:

```
DateSQL    DateText   Week Year Month Day Weekday  Period YearPeriod MonthPeriod
2014-12-29 29-12-2014    1 2014    12  29 Monday        1       2015           1
2014-12-30 30-12-2014    1 2014    12  30 Tuesday       1       2015           1
2014-12-31 31-12-2014    1 2014    12  31 Wednesday     1       2015           1
2015-01-01 01-01-2015    1 2015     1   1 Thursday      1       2015           1
2015-01-02 02-01-2015    1 2015     1   2 Friday        1       2015           1
2015-01-03 03-01-2015    1 2015     1   3 Saturday      1       2015           1
2015-01-04 04-01-2015    1 2015     1   4 Sunday        1       2015           1
2015-01-05 05-01-2015    2 2015     1   5 Monday        1       2015           1
```

It can solve a lot of problems in query's for determine several date issues. For example: 29-12-2014 belongs to week 1 of year 2015.
Or: 31-12-2015 belongs to week 53 of year 2015, but (in our case) to period 13 (and not 14, in our 4-weekly period).